# Dymanically changing table content in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Requirement: In our application, when I click on scan button, the Status will be "In Progress". I should keep clicking on "Refresh button", the "Stop" Status changes to "Time, date, year", it means the scan has completed. Below is the piece of code I written, but its not working.

```
public void verifyScanComplete(String networkName)
    {
        int i=0;
        try{
    //here I am searching for the string "In Progress" in the page
        List<WebElement> stopStatus = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='In Progress']"));
    //this is the element stop status which will change from "In Progress" to "dd/mm/yy"
        WebElement stopStatusChanged = driver .findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='div_scan_set']/form/div/table/tbody/tr/td[text()='"+networkName+"']/../td[10]"));

     while ((stopStatusChanged.getText().contains("In Progress")))
     {

        WebUtils.sleep(40000);
        driver.navigate().refresh();
       i++;

     }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

Comment: Define "not working". Thanks.

Comment: @Rashmi - Do you getting any error? If yes then please paste error with question.

Comment: @alecxe - By mistake you have put source edited comment to here?

Comment: About your comment : Define "not working". I feel it is text which you tried to put as summary when you edited question. OR is it real comment and you are saying to questioner that?

Comment: I have mentioned the expected result in the Requirement. I am getting exception here.

Comment: @RashmiPatil @HelpingHands I guess what alecxe was looking for is the `stacktrace` it's often easier to find the problem with stacktrace if you are expert on that `language`

Comment: @Saifur - May be your are right..